# Why was Credence bleeding?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In the scene where Graves gives Credence his Deathly Hallows necklace, Credence's hand is shown to be bleeding. Why? Was it related to his

> being an Obscurial?

Comment: I'd assume they're the result of his "punishment", but I can't find any confirmation

Comment: In the previous scene we see him being punished; *As if on autopilot, CREDENCE removes his belt. MARY LOU stands and extends her hand, taking the belt. In silence, she turns and walks up the stairs, CREDENCE obediently following.*

Comment: @JasonBaker - I'm assuming that [this](https://youtu.be/W6ZP8axYo70?t=620) is what you are referring to by "punishment".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It's strongly implied that it's caused by his stepmother's abuse.

I don't remember anything in either the movie or the screenplay explicitly stating that Credence bleeding was the result of beaten. However, he only is seen bleeding after Mary Lou makes him take off his belt and give it to her. That is heavily implied to mean she is going to beat him with it. He looks upset about it, like he knows and dreads what's about to happen, and his adoptive sister also looks bothered by it.

> “Credence moves around to the bottom of the stairs, falling silent at the severe expression on Mary Lou’s face.
>
> CREDENCE
>   
> *I’m sorry, Ma. I didn’t realize it was so late.*
>
> As if on autopilot, Credence removes his belt. Mary Lou stands and extends her hand, taking the belt. In silence, she turns and walks up the stairs—Credence obediently following.
>   Modesty moves to the bottom of the stairs, watching them go, a look of fear and upset on her face.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

This particular instance isn't stated outright, but it is made clear that he was abused. Tina had said that Mary Lou Barebone abused all the children under her care, and had a particularly cruel way of handling Credence. She had witnessed this herself and it was one of the main reasons she was so determined to take down the Second Salemers.

His abuse was also the driving force behind what happened to him, so it makes sense that we would be shown some of it. We are probably supposed to connect the facts that Credence is habitually abused, that Mary Lou Barebone made him hand over his belt (which he was clearly upset about), and that his hand was bleeding afterwards to come to the conclusion that Mary Lou Barebone hit him with the belt until he bled.